# Set an incoming value to a new value

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

How do I set an incoming value to a new value in msbuild?

Lets say I have this

```
  msbuild /t:package /p:revision=2.2
```

in my msbuild file I want to change the revision to another value in another variable.
Let say I have:

```
 $(Version)
```

I know want my Version value to set Revision value.

```
revision = Version
```

How?

Example 
 You get revision 1.0.0.0 in but want to set revision to what you have in your version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using PropertyGroups and Conditions.  Save this MsBuild markup as "test.proj".

```
<Project DefaultTargets="VersionTest" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Version Condition="'$(Revision)' != ''">$(Revision)</Version>
    <Version Condition="'$(Version)' == ''">0.0.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="VersionTest">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Revision is: $(Revision)" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Version is: $(Version)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

From a command prompt run `msbuild.exe test.proj`

```
VersionTest:
  Revision is:
  Version is: 0.0.0.0
```

Then run: `msbuild test.proj /p:Revision=1.0.0.0`

```
VersionTest:
  Revision is: 1.0.0.0
  Version is: 1.0.0.0
```

Comment: But what if u want the opposite. You get revision 1.0.0.0 in but want to set revision to what you have in your version?

Comment: Please articulate this in an update to your post so we don't clutter mine with probing questions :)

Comment: Ok sorry for that. Done

Comment: On this update, you'd want to understand how expressions work in the previous example then apply those concepts to your new requirements.  This way you now understand how to fish!